# Angular - How to stop trigger all form field validation when update a single input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a form that contains the following inputs: first name, last name, username and password.

I can generate a random password using a button, using set/patchValue into the control will trigger all validation (for first name, last name and username), but I want to trigger the validation just for my input (password)

```
this.userDetailsFormGroup
        .get('password')
        ?.patchValue(usersData.data.toString());
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to add a second parameter to the `patchValue` method call and specify `emitEvent: false`. Something like this: `patchValue(usersData.data.toString(), {emitEvent: false})`

Comment: I tried with emitEvent and onlySelf parameters, but without any results :( . After patchValue, all validators are triggered

Comment: I made a test project on stackblitz, when I press Change Value, I want to trigger the validation just for First Name input, not for all https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-2n7v6o?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your buttons have the `type="button"` attribute on them (except for the Save button, of course), otherwise they will trigger the submit event because the default `type` of a button is `submit`. That's why you get the validation errors on all the fields.

Another note: When you update the value like you do (by grabbing the `firstName` control and setting a primitive value on it), you can get away with using `setValue` instead of `patchValue`. The `patchValue` is useful when you are setting a "complex" value and you only update it partially. For example, you can do something like this:

```
this.userDetailsFormGroup.patchValue({ firstName: usersData.data.toString() });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Octavian, I forgot to add (type="button"), now it's working as expected